# Update Tomcat to point at custom domain

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6

To navigate to local tomcat installation I use `http://localhost:8080`

Can Tomcat be configured so that when I run it locally it still navigates to `http://localhost:8080` but I can specify a different host name ?

e.g when navigate to `http://<MACHINE_NAME>.com:8080` redirects to `http://localhost:8080` .

This is just for local development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I may need to modify hosts file : 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29